# How to use user custom pulgin in qgis in centos

Tags: python, centos, qgis

I have made qgis plugin using python in window i put it in gis/python/plugin directory to add it in qgis but in centos I am unable to find such directory in which I put it and use it in qgis and please let me know how to use our custom plugin in qgis in centos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right place to put your custom QGIS plugins in Linux is:

```
$HOME/.qgis2/python/plugins/
```